# How to pass in a dynamic connectionstring to a crystal reports .xsd file?

Tags: xml, crystal-reports, xsd

I have an xsd file running some crystal reports, and I need to be able to send in a conectionstring to the xsd to tell the reports what database to connect to.  Is this possible?

Comment: For my own knowledge, how does an xsd file run a crystal report? I thought XML-type files were just a data storage format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the designer.cs file of the XSD.  You should see a line of code referencing ConnectionString which you can then modify (I believe there should be one for each table referenced in it).